# Importing Java libraries into settings.gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-project build with an uncommon folder hierarchy. Rather than having all the subprojects contained within the root project, the subprojects are scattered throughout the file system. As a consequence, I'm overwriting the 
`project.projectDir` property of many of the subprojects as suggested in this post: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-include-sub-projects-in-settings-gradle-file/5096

I'd like to use Java's Paths library (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathClass.html) to make it easier to work with paths. However, I'm unsure how/if I can important the java.nio.file library into my settings.gradle file. Simply `import java.nio.file` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was trying to import something that doesn't exist. Using `import java.nio.file.Paths` seems to work.